# Django url unique url open

Tags: django, unique, slug

I use django 1.10.5.
I have a problem with open unique url, views:

```
entry = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
```

model field:

```
slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
```

i need to detect slug with identical string, for example i have slug xyz and xYz i need to open other pages, now django display 500 page on production.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.single_post, name='single_post'),
```

And error message:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /pZw/ get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!
```

how i can detect if is identical?

Comment: I see in the view the slug field accepts both type of pattern. Can you please share the exception ?

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned at /pzw/
get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!

Comment: And what is not self-explanatory about that message?

Comment: Yep, i understand but i need to check and compare url patterns are case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Well what's happening is you are getting two results where get_object_or_404 is expected to return only 1. 
Your field slug is not unique and have some inconsistency. 
Can you try this.

```
entry = get_object_or_404(Post, slug__exact=slug)
```

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned at /pZw/
get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!

Comment: `__exact` is the default lookup, specifying it explicitly is not gonna change the behaviour.